# How to make an Object with spread (...) notation reactive?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to change the opacity attribute of an object and make that change reactive:

**Component.vue:**

```
<child-component :common="itemCommon"></child-component>

<script>
data () {
  return {
    rest: {}
  }
},

computed: {
  itemCommon () {
    return {
      item: {
        opacity: 1,
        ...this.rest
      }
    }
  }
},

beforeMount () {
  this.rest = { name: 'a' }
}
<script>
```

**childComponent.vue:**

```
<script>
props: {
  common: {
    type: Object,
    default () {
      return {}
    }
  }
},

beforeMount () {
  this.common.item.opacity = 0
}
</script>
```

The `opacity` attribute won't be set to `0`. Vue doesn't consider `itemCommon`

How to modify the code so `itemCommon` becomes reactive?

Comment: Can you created a fiddle of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, vue watches the changes on components' `data` properties, and change the view when it sees a `data` change. So to make some data *reactive*, we have to declare it in a component's `data`. You don't have `opacity` in either component here, so it's probably not picked up by vue. Adding it to the parent's `data` should fix it, but you'll get a warning like `directly setting prop in child`, then you should move `this.common.item.opacity = 0` to the parent. You can find plenty searching the warning but here briefly: `prop` will commonly be changed in the parent, changing it also in the child is confusing, and by design, the child provides functionality/interface, the parent, who makes use of the child, give data to the child in runtime, trusting the child handling the data with the functionality we expect, so we achieve *loose coupling*. (this is also usually called a one-way data flow)